# Saving files from an iOS app extension to the containing app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios-app-extension

I'm working on adding the ability to use the share button to allow users to save files for use with my main application.  Multiple file types (image, video, audio, pdf, etc) need to be supported.

A general use case would be:
The user takes a picture with the standard Camera app or audio recording using the Voice Memos app.
User clicks the Share button and selects my extension from the share list.
Dialog opens up giving the user to opportunity to give a description for the file.
File is saved to where my main app (the containing app) can later access and process it.

I've been able to get to the point where I am prompted to share the file, but I have not been able to find a location to successfully save to that my main app can later read from.  Is this even possible?  Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

I am currently doing this using Xamarin so debugging is not supported (and logging is minimal).  If someone has an answer in Objective C, that would at least help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you find a good way to do it ?Do you have a sample code ?

Comment: @Dave.Lebr1 What you can do is make sure your app and the extension are in the same app group and you can read and write files from that common directory.  I wrote files there are used an NSUserDefaults that also used the shared group: NSUserDefaults sharedPrefs = new NSUserDefaults ("group.com.name", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);

Comment: I find how to share with the NSUserDefaults but the problem is that when I have big file liker over 40 mb ... the app is crashing. So, I can't get the data into the host app. But If I save the file inside the group app directory and get it back from the host app I think this will work.

Comment: Are you trying to write the file to the NSUserDefaults or to the directory? I use the userDefaults to keep track of the URL and metadata of my files while they are being imported.  I don't believe I've tried for any files larger than 20 megs or so.  What error appears in the log for the crash?

Comment: Oh alright ! Yea it crash with memory warning... because NSUserDefaults can't handle big data.. So, I send the information via the NSUserDefaults wich is the url to the file and I save the file to the directory with NSFileManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to do.

First, your app and your app extension should belong to the same app group:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19

Then you can access the shared storage with something like this:

```
var groupUrl = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetContainerUrl ("stackoverflow.com.mygroup")
```

Now you can access files in the directory pointed by groupUrl.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin's guide to creating Share extensions for iOS: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_extensions/

Comment: I've used that guide and it has gotten me as far as being able to respond to the share event, but I was having issues saving the file from the extension and reopening it in the application.